# My request in ajax with PUT method is returning error 500

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax's put method to update my table, which is stored on a rest server but I'm getting 500 error (intenal server error), I do not know what to do, can anyone help me? I'm new to ajax programming

```
$(document).on('click', "#modalgravar", function(){

var eURL = 'http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/Grupo/';
    var Ecdgrupo = $("#Cdgrupoedit").val();
    var Egrupo = $("#grupoedit").val();
    var eData ={"Cdgrupo": Ecdgrupo, "Grupos": Egrupo};

alert(JSON.stringify(eData));

    $.ajax({
       type:'PUT',
       url: eURL,
       data: JSON.stringify(eData),
        success: function(){
        alert("Editado!");
              },
        error: function(){
            alert("ERRO:  O grupo não foi editado!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are posting code from your client side, but status 500 means that the error is happening on your server side. Can you post the code from the server as well?

Comment: @PPetkov Unfortunately I can not post the server code but I am sure that it is compatible with the PUT. From the little I understand of Ajax I believe the server is not recognizing that my call is a put, since the error is returned as: OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/Grupo/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! The problem was that there were missing headers on the server, so I was having trouble with cors.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `contentType: 'application/json',`

Make sure your api endpoint reponses to PUT request with a RequestBody you are sending in your ajax request.

Comment: I added application/json but it did not work too. Same error. In IE works but in chrome no.

Comment: Works in IE? 
Try disabling chrome extensions like AdBlocks.

Comment: I dont use any Adblocks

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use PUT method in Datasnap You need to change procedure name on server side. Name should start with 'accept' like 'acceptURIMethodName'. So in this case propably 'acceptGrupo'. Then method URL will be: 
http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TCadastros/acceptGrupo/